# How does SQL handle conversion between int / string operand and column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to understand how comparison is done when the operand is integer and column type is string and vice versa.

**Sample table**

My table is as follows:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE tbl1;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col2  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col3  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col4  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Its content is as follows:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl1;
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| val1 | NULL |    7 | 7    |
| val4 | NULL | NULL | abc  |
| val2 |    2 |    8 | 8    |
| val3 |    3 |   18 | 18   |
+------+------+------+------+
```

**Some queries**

1. Comparing string with INT column:

   ```
   mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE "9" > col3;
   +------+------+------+------+
   | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
   +------+------+------+------+
   | val1 | NULL |    7 | 7    |
   | val2 |    2 |    8 | 8    |
   +------+------+------+------+
   ```
2. Comparing integer with VARCHAR column:

   ```
   mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE 9 > col4;
   +------+------+------+------+
   | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
   +------+------+------+------+
   | val1 | NULL |    7 | 7    |
   | val4 | NULL | NULL | abc  |
   | val2 |    2 |    8 | 8    |
   +------+------+------+------+
   ```

**Doubts**

1. Does SQL correctly converts between integer opreand / column and string operand / column before performing any comparison / mathematical operation? Is there any exception / detail to it?
2. Why second query returned row with `col4` having `abc`?

**PS:** I am not talking in the context of any specific database. So, if there is any database specific details / behavior variation to it, please share.

Comment: [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Answer (score 0):

When an integer is compared to a string, the sting is converted to a number.

The number is based on the leading digits of the string.  If the string has no digits, then the value is treated as `0`.

Comment: What do you mean by "The number is based on the leading digits of the string."? Both queries correctly filtered out 18. Do you mean to say if the string was "a1bc2" then the integer equivalent would be 1, or something like that?

Comment: @anir . . . The string `'a1bd2'` has no leading digits, it would be converted to `0`.  The string `'1bd2'` has a single leading digit, `1`, so it would be converted to that value.